# Exclude words from a list that contain one or more characters from another list python

Tags: python, list, filter, character

I have a list as an input which contains words, these words sometimes contain non-ascii letter characters, I need to filter out the entire word if they contain letters that are not in the ascii list.

So the if the input is:

```
words = ['Hello', 'my','dear', 'de7ar', 'Fri?ends', 'Friends']
```

I need the Output:

```
['Hello', 'my', 'dear', Friends']


words = ['Hello', 'my','dear', 'de7ar', 'Fri?ends', 'Friends']
al = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ascii_letters = [char for char in al] 

filtered_words=[]
```

I tried it with this:

```
for el in words:  
    try:
        words in ascii_letters 
    except FALSE: 
        filtered_words.append(el)
```

and this

```
filtered words = [ele for ele in words if all(ch not in ele for ch in ascii_letters)]
```

but both of them do not result in what I need - I do understand why but since I have only been learning python for a week I fail to adjust them to make them do what I want them to, maybe someone knows how to handle this (without using any libraries)?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 1):

You could check whether your alphabet is a superset of the words:

```
>>> [*filter(set(al).issuperset, words)]
['Hello', 'my', 'dear', 'Friends']
```

Btw, better don't hardcode that alphabet (I've seen quite a few people do that and forget letters) but import it:

```
from string import ascii_letters as al
```

Comment: You forgot about [`str.isaplha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha): `list(filter(str.isalpha, words))`

Comment: You're right, I did, but that differs. It rejects the empty string and it accepts 131241 different characters, not just those 52.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate trough the words in the words list to check whether all letters are ion ASCII or you can use the `all()` function:

```py
words = ['Hello', 'my','dear', 'de7ar', 'Fri?ends', 'Friends']
al = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ascii_letters = [char for char in al]

out = []
for word in words:
    not_in_ascii = False
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in ascii_letters:
            not_in_ascii = True
    if not_in_ascii:
        continue
    out.append(word)
```

It is also possible with list comprehension and `all()` as you tried:

```py
out = [word for word in words if all([letter in ascii_letters for letter in word])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in words if i.isalpha()]
```

Result:

```
['Hello', 'my', 'dear', 'Friends']
```